# javascript go to herf and scroll to element

Tags: javascript, html, tags

my question is how can i get this code href to a link and when the link is loaded scroll to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".jumper").on("click", function( e ) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("body, html").animate({ 
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('name') ).offset().top 
    }, 600);

});
```

})

this are the links. all the links have to herf to the same page, after i clicked the sublink(the link with the class="jumper") it have's to jump to that page and scroll to that element

the attr name is to indicate to which div it haves to go

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href='cursus.php'><span>Cursus</span></a>
              <li class='last'><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php' name='5'><span>Android Phone & tablet</span></a></li>  <ul>
               <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php' name='4'><span>Software</span></a></li>
               <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php' name='3'><span>Hardware</span></a></li>
               <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php' name='2' ><span>Windows 7 & 8</span></a></li>
               <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php' name='1' ><span>Microsoft office</span></a></li>

         </ul>
    </li>
```

does anyone have the answers i'm looking for?

Comment: If you have divs with ids `#1 #2 #3 #4` then use `scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).attr('name')).offset().top` or with classes `scrollTop: $('.'+$(this).attr('name')).offset().top`

Answer (score 2):

try using it this way...

```
<li class='has-sub'><a href='cursus.php'><span>Cursus</span></a>
          <li class='last'><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php#5' ><span>Android Phone & tablet</span></a></li>  <ul>
           <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php#4'><span>Software</span></a></li>
           <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php#3' ><span>Hardware</span></a></li>
           <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php#2'  ><span>Windows 7 & 8</span></a></li>
           <li><a class="jumper" href='cursus.php#1' ><span>Microsoft office</span></a></li>

     </ul>
</li>
```

and in your cursus.php page

```
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
});
```

Comment: cursus.php is one page with sub menus divided in divs each div has a id so when i click on the sub menu it has to skip the page cursus.php and go to cursus.php #1 in a scrolling motion

Comment: @user3638080  sorry is the whole code in the same page...?

Comment: btw this works but not how i liked it to work because it not starts on the top of the pages ands scroll down

Comment: @user3638080 if every thing is int the same .php file...then href='#2' should also work..

Comment: I tried this trick for jumping around to multiple elements and after you have clicked a few you end up with bad offsets.